# The XML views under the drawerLayout or navigationView are not displayed [Android]

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, view, navigation

I was facing an issue, in which any view in layout activity below the views [drawerlayout or the navigationView] are not displayed (they are displayed in the bottom of the screen and not rise up).

Kindly, find my activity XML layout file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BoardUI">



    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_selector_text_layout"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/navigationviewtoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


<
   
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    
    
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The button [last element] is not displayed. Note: I don't want to add this button in the first item.

Answer (score 0):

- drawer layout must become your root view . so you need to re arrange the views in the xml to be as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!-- The main content view displays when the drawer is hidden -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/navigationviewtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_arrow_back_ios_24"
            app:title="my custom toolbar"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white" />
        <!-- your main content   -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="my content" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

so the layout would behave like this :

[image]

- i also noticed you wanna add your own toolbar and discard the one provided by the theme . to do so you need to define the NoActionBar theme in your app manifest

```
<!-- inside your manifest <application> tag bock  -->
android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light.NoActionBar"
```